# show that R is an equivalent relation

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $m>1$ be an integer, the relation $R$ on $\mathbb{N}$ given by 
$R=\{(a,b):a\equiv b \mod m\}$ , that is $aRb \Rightarrow a\equiv b\mod m$ where $a\equiv b\mod m$ iff $m$ divides $a-b$. Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: What've you done so far? Do you already have reflexivity, transitivity, symmetry...? Show your work, please.

Comment: @JohnHabert Why do you change $a=b(mod\ m)$ to $a\equiv b\mod m$ everywhere? This is not the only notation, and now you further confuse the original author of the question, because they use different notation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that $R$ is

1) Reflexive: for each $n: nRn$. Show that for each $n$: $n=n(mod\ m)$.

2) Symmetric: for each $n,n': nRn' \implies n'Rn$. Show that if $n=n'(mod\ m)$ then $n'=n(mod\ m)$.

3) Transitive: for each $n,n',n'': nRn',n'Rn'' \implies nRn''$. Show that if $n=n'(mod\ m)$ and $n'=n''(mod\ m)$, then $n=n''(mod\ m)$.

In each point explicitly express what $a=b(mod\ m)$ means, and show what is required. Tell us if you have some *specific* problems at some step.